# _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Tags: pickle, python-3.6

l'm using python3.6/  .  l pickled my file using `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`

when l load it as follow :

```
with open('data.sav', 'rb') as handle:
      data = pickle.load(handle)
```

l get the following error :

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: I get the same problem with 3.6 but cannot find anything useful to do with this problem. I'm considering using other serialization library

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while and maybe you have already found a solution.

In my case, the issue was due to the pickle file being corrupted. You could try to check the file's integrity with **sha256sum**, **md5sum** or something similar.

Hope it helps.